# send variable to <a href>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a option selector, and I want the value of the chosen option to be based on to a `<a href="#top"> tag. So that <br>Godfather links to #top,<br>Shawshank to #middle<br>Fightclub to #bottom<br><br>`
I have the following code:

```
<select id="one">
    <option></option>       
    <option value="1">Godfather</option>
    <option value="2">Shawshank</option>
    <option value="3">Fightclub</option>
</select>
```

Javascript

```
var url;


    $("select").change(function () {

        //console.log($(this).val());

        var val = $(this).val();

        if (val == "1") {
            $("#image").css({"background-image": "url(image/godfather.jpg)"});
            url = "goodfather";
        }
        if (val == "2") {
            $("#image").css({"background-image": "url(image/shawshank.jpg)"});
            url = "shawshank";
        }
        if (val == "3") {
            $("#image").css({"background-image": "url(image/fightclub.jpg)"});
                            url = "fightclub";
```

Comment: The purpose of your question is clear, but not the HTML output you want to achieve. Could you please add the `<a>` element you want to amend to the sample in the question

Comment: i have posted what you are looking for i think. but isn't it better to change window location on the select change event to reroute directly?

Comment: thank you @RoryMcCrossan but mtizziani already answered my question. I ll make sure to be more clear next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <a href="">My Link</a>
    <select id="one">
        <option></option>       
        <option value="1">Godfather</option>
        <option value="2">Shawshank</option>
        <option value="3">Fightclub</option>
    </select>

    <div id="goodfather"></div>
    <div id="shawshank"></div>
    <div id="fightclub"></div>
```

here the changes in the js:

```
var url;
$("select").change(function () {
  //console.log($(this).val());
  var val = $(this).val();
  if (val == "1") {
    $("#image").css({"background-image": "url(image/godfather.jpg)"});
    url = "goodfather";
  }
  if (val == "2") {
    $("#image").css({"background-image": "url(image/shawshank.jpg)"});
    url = "shawshank";
  }
  if (val == "3") {
    $("#image").css({"background-image": "url(image/fightclub.jpg)"});
    url = "fightclub";
  }
  $('a').attr('href', '#' + url).text(url);
});
```

working fine in fiddle if this is what you are searching for: https://jsfiddle.net/v89c4tg6/

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.
The `attr()` method sets or returns attributes and values of the selected elements. When this method is used to set attribute values, it sets one or more attribute/value pairs for the set of matched elements.

Set the attribute and value:

```
$(selector).attr(attribute,value)
```

See [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
$('#movie-link').attr('href', '#' + url);
```

Here we are setting the href of movie-link as `#url`.
eg: `#godfather`

```
$('#movie-link').text(url);
```

This rewrites the text of `movie-link` with `url`.

```js
var url;


$("select").change(function() {

  //console.log($(this).val());

  var val = $(this).val();

  if (val == "1") {
    $("#image").css({
      "background-image": "url('https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41fxpecg67L.jpg')"
    });
    url = "goodfather";
  }
  if (val == "2") {
    $("#image").css({
      "background-image": "url('http://68.media.tumblr.com/f60260c4de4eb3f44ed69c1b84aba752/tumblr_nyjjedR9C21s80h8lo1_1280.jpg')"
    });
    url = "shawshank";
  }
  if (val == "3") {
    $("#image").css({
      "background-image": "url('https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/project_modules/disp/8c97ea7728123.560b0a46e7bb7.PNG')"
    });
    url = "fightclub";
  }
  $('#movie-link').attr('href', '#' + url);
  $('#movie-link').text(url);
});
```

```css
#image {
  margin: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="one">
    <option>Select option</option>       
    <option value="1">Godfather</option>
    <option value="2">Shawshank</option>
    <option value="3">Fightclub</option>
</select>
<br/>
<div id="image"></div>
<a id="movie-link" href="#">Select Link</a>
```